# Tank Auth: Account Confirmation Email Activation Code Expired

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

When user click on "Finish Your Registration" link, it shows `The activation code you entered is incorrect or expired.`
 Here is tank_auth configuration:

```
$config['allow_registration'] = TRUE;
$config['captcha_registration'] = FALSE;
$config['email_activation'] = TRUE;
$config['email_activation_expire'] = 60*60*24*2;
$config['email_account_details'] = TRUE;
```

It was working fine when I was using the original TA views. Not sure where and how to debug.

Codeigniter v2.1.2, PHP 5

Comment: have you modified any TA view?

Comment: yes. I did. Does that affect the activation code expiration?

Comment: Please redownload TA, and use default views (make backup for your own modified), see if there is same error. If not you have changed view in a way that `$this->input->post('')` does not fetch activation code. I hope you see my point.